# How to predict time to auto-increment exhaustion with Prometheus?

Tags: mysql, prometheus

We're using the following query to alert on MySQL tables that reach the auto-increment limit:

```
max by(app_kubernetes_io_instance, schema, table, column)
 (mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column * 100 / mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column_max) > 95
```

Reaching the maximum depends on several factors such as insert rate and size of the auto-increment column.

I would like to use `predict_linear` to create an alert that triggers 48h before the maximum is reached. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

By time, meaning time remaining until the autoincrement reaches the 95% threshold of the maximum? I imagine you would be able to do something like this:

`T * (mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column_max - mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column) / (predict_linear(mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column[1h], T) - mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column)`

where T is some configurable time you're predicting autoincrement over.

Comment: Thanks Larry. The output of your query is the number of records left, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Alert if it runs out within 48h:

```
mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column_max - predict_linear(mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column[12h], 48*3600) < 0
```

Percentage in 48h based on 12h of data:

```
max by(app_kubernetes_io_instance, schema, table, column)
  (predict_linear(mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column[12h], 48*3600) * 100 / mysql_info_schema_auto_increment_column_max)
```